# AWS Managed Grafana - Unable to connect to Amazon Document Db as MongoDB data source

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, grafana, managed

hello i am unable to connect to document DB from amazon licensed managed grafana service . Both services are in same region US East ohio.

i am  using following conn string to connect with certificate CA contents in place

mongodb://docdb-2021-11-10-12-15-54.cluster-cqyoommuvdph.us-east-2.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/?ssl=true&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false

[image: MongoDB Datasource]

[image: Error - timeout]

I am getting following error:

504 Gateway Time-out

## 504 Gateway Time-out

although both services are in same region. What could be the issue?